# Running SCIMP for various n

Tags: plot, linear-programming, scip

I have a linear program where I can put in numbers for n and it gives me the ouput of the LP for this specific n. I want to do this now for various n=10...1000. Is there a technique where I dont have to do it manually fpr each n and instead does this automatically and outputs the solution of the LP for each n in a file? I like to plot the graph later on.

This is my linear program:

```
#Specify the number of n for the linear program.
param n := 5000;

#This is the set of probabilities of 
set N := {1 .. n};
#We specify the variables for the probabilities p_1,...p_n.
var p[<i> in N] real >= 0; 

#These are the values of the vector c. It specifies a constant for each p_i.
param c[<i> in N] := i/n ;

#We define the entries a_{ij} of the Matrix A.
defnumb a(i,j) := 
            if i < j then 0 
            else if i == j then i 
            else 1 end end;

#The objective function.
maximize prob: sum <i> in N : c[i] * p[i];

#The condition which needs to be fulfilled.
 subto condition:
    forall <i> in N:
      sum <j> in N: a(i,j) * p[j] <= 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give arguments via the console with:

```
-D n=[number you want] -o [output file]
```

Then you could iterate several n by just using a shell script, e.g.,

```
for i in {1..100}
do
 zimpl -D n=$i -o 'output_'$i yourfile.zpl
done
```